# PySpark DF and RDD encoding of latin letters

Tags: python, apache-spark, encoding, character-encoding, pyspark

I have to import `CSV` file in `Spark` and convert it in `DF` and then in `RDD` before process it.

First I import the full `CSV` file as a `DF`

```
stopwords_df = (
    sqlc
    .read
    .format('csv')
    .option('header', True)
    .option('delimiter', ';')
    .option('encoding', 'latin1')
    .load('/mnt/sparkdata/stopwords.csv', schema = stopSchema)
    .repartition(72)
)
```

Then I select the suitable words only and convert this into a set

```
stopwords_set = set(
    stopwords_df
    .filter(f.col('retain').isNull())
    .rdd
    .map(lambda x: x[0].encode('latin1')) # the [0] is to extract strings from Rows
    .collect()
)
```

I'm messing up with the encoding and I don't know how to fix this.

If I "show" the `DF`, the Latin letters will be shown correctly (sperò)

```
stopwords_df.show(100, truncate = False)

+--------------+--------+------+----------+------+
|word          |language|type  |doubletype|retain|
+--------------+--------+------+----------+------+
|informava     |IT      |verbo |null      |null  |
|sperò         |IT      |verbo |null      |null  |
|four          |EN      |null  |null      |null  |
```

But this won't happen if I show the RDD

```
(
    stopwords_df
    .filter(f.col('word') == r'sperò')
    .rdd
    .first()
)

Row(word=u'sper\xf2', language=u'IT', type=u'verbo', doubletype=None, retain=None)
```

With `UTF-8 encoding` it will also go worst

```
+--------------+--------+------+----------+------+
|word          |language|type  |doubletype|retain|
+--------------+--------+------+----------+------+
|thanks        |EN      |saluto|null      |null  |
|fossero       |IT      |verbo |null      |null  |
|sper�         |IT      |verbo |null      |null  |
```

Could you please suggest me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing this line:

```
Row(word=u'sper\xf2)
```

It Does imply that you are using Python 3. The default encoding for Python 3 is utf-8 and it supports ò by default.

Hence, ò is replaced with \xf2 when you specified to encode it as latin1.

Why don't you collect without the encoding as latin1?

```
stopwords_set = set(
    stopwords_df
    .filter(f.col('retain').isNull())
    .rdd
    .collect()
)
```

Let me know if this helps.
Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I answered this from mobile and hence, couldn't format it. I appreciate your patience.